# Android activity relaunch returning from camera intent in Tablet

Tags: tablet, launch, android-camera-intent

I have opened the camera intent from activity but when I take a picture and return on activity, onActivityForResult is calling also activity is again relaunching only in Tablet not phone,
means to say all activity is again loading after return from camera intent in Tablet.its a very strange.
Can you please suggest me what problem is getting on Tablet.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Change manifest settings
write this in `<activity>` in manifest

```
android:launchMode="singleInstance"
```

Thanks